# How do I change the Icon for a USB device?

Tags: icon, customization

My phone uses a standard icon when mounted. I just want to replace that icon with a custom one.

[image: screenshot1]

I'm opening a PNG image in Preview and copying the image, then pasting onto the icon in the Get Info window, but I get the system PNG icon instead of the image itself:

[image: screenshot2]

How do you use a custom image? OSX gives you no feedback on this at all.

**Update**: After some further investigation, it appears that the image is being set correctly in `.VolumeIcons.icns`

[image: screenshot3]

So for whatever reason, Finder is refusing to display it correctly. Is there some kind of icon format requirement that Finder isn't telling me?

---

**Update:** Now the cut-n-paste method works fine. I have not changed anything, so I have no idea what was wrong before. I can only chalk this up to a Finder bug.

Comment: Please remove images and other stuff from the question to keep it simple. The answer should contain the details, and current answers already contains enough good details. Thanks!

Comment: @Sorin this is a question regarding glitchy UI behavior; images are perfectly appropriate and helpful in describing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just drag and drop :)

sometimes it does not work so, you do a simple:

- COPY: copy to clipboard the icon you want to use
- SELECT: select the icon you want to remove
- PASTE: paste it

[image]

[image]

Comment: This answer is baffling to me. It's as if you didn't read my question at all. I was already using cut-n-paste to replace the icon. Furthermore, the .VolumeIcons.icns file whose screenshot you modified for your answer is only created _after_ changing the icon.

Comment: cut-n'-paste works every time, so, if it does not work for you, something happen, just restart and try again. I't a Finder feature, not a bug.

Comment: The fact that this _did not_ work for me was almost certainly a bug, because it works fine now.

Comment: I have had some App Icons not work with cut-n-paste, in the paste, but nowadays they seem to work okay, perhaps apple has ironed some of these bugs out.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use DiskUtility with Repair disk for USB memory.
Icon appears correctly.